# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException with system language

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, macos, jvm

When I start a spring boot application, I have this exception when I use Turkish system language. But, if I change to English system language, spring boot application works fine. I can't give more details about the problem, because changing the system language is enough. But I want to continue using Turkish system language.

If any information is requested, I am willing to share.

- os: macOS 12.1
- java: jdk11

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'categorySlugMap': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Error attempting to apply AttributeConverter; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Error attempting to apply AttributeConverter
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:160)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:416)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1788)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:882)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
    at com.sample.api.SampleApi.main(SampleApi.java:12)
Caused by: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Error attempting to apply AttributeConverter; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Error attempting to apply AttributeConverter
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:408)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:257)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:528)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:178)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy356.findAll(Unknown Source)
    at com.sample.api.services.listing.model.CategorySlugMap.generate(CategorySlugMap.java:49)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:389)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:157)
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Error attempting to apply AttributeConverter
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.converter.AttributeConverterSqlTypeDescriptorAdapter$2.doConversion(AttributeConverterSqlTypeDescriptorAdapter.java:148)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.converter.AttributeConverterSqlTypeDescriptorAdapter$2.extract(AttributeConverterSqlTypeDescriptorAdapter.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:257)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:253)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:329)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3068)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1866)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.hydrateEntityState(Loader.java:1794)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1767)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1615)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:745)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:1008)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:964)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2838)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2820)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2652)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2647)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:506)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:396)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1404)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1562)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1530)
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:165)
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:76)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:355)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:371)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:204)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:657)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:621)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:605)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:366)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant com.sample.core.entity.listing.listing.OldTradeType.DAİLY_RENT
    at java.base/java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:240)
    at com.sample.core.model.converters.LowerCaseEnumConverter.convertToEntityAttribute(LowerCaseEnumConverter.java:27)
    at com.sample.core.model.converters.LowerCaseEnumConverter.convertToEntityAttribute(LowerCaseEnumConverter.java:4)
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.convert.internal.JpaAttributeConverterImpl.toDomainValue(JpaAttributeConverterImpl.java:45)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.converter.AttributeConverterSqlTypeDescriptorAdapter$2.doConversion(AttributeConverterSqlTypeDescriptorAdapter.java:140)
    ... 78 common frames omitted
```

Comment: You should include the complete stacktrace for the exception in your question.  Use the [EDIT button](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70813758/edit).

Comment: added stack trace

Answer (score 1):

The stacktrace indicates that the underlying cause of the `BeanCreationException` is a failure while trying to translate something to a `enum` value.  Furthermore, it looks like this is happening while trying to deserialize ("rehydrate") a data retrieved from a database.

Furthermore, the message texts imply that you have stored the enum value `OldTradeType.DAİLY_RENT` in your database.  The stacktrace says Hibernate cannot deserialize that because the deserializer does not recognize that particular enum value ... at the moment.

So here's my theory.

1. Your localization scheme includes having different variants of the `OldTradeType` enum with values that depend on the system locale; i.e the "system language".  (I don't know how ... but somehow.)
2. You have created objects and stored them when the locale was set to English.
3. You have now changed the locale
4. The locale changes mean that the version of thd `OldTradeType` enum that your app is currently using is when no longer compatible with the version used when serializing.  So it throws an exception because it cannot deserialize it.

---

If this is correct, there are a few approaches to solving this.

1. Change the way that you represent the enum values so that the in-memory `enum` types don't depend on the locale settings.
2. Change the enum converter class so that it map the locale specific in-memory enums to a local independent representation.
3. Change the enum converter class so that it understands all of the possible the locale specific representations in the database ... and maps to the appropriate one when deserializing.
4. When you switch system the system locale reset the database; i.e. throw away all of the data.

I can't tell you which would be more appropriate.  It depends on your application.

<sup>(Q: And I give you example code, or a reference?  A: No.)</sup>

---

This is happening during bean creation, but that's not the cause of the problem.  The problem is in your code<sup>1</sup> rather than SpringBoot or Hibernate.

<sup>1 - Or if the `com.sample` classes are example code ... the problem is that you are using the example in a way that it isn't designed to cope with.</sup>